# string array in inspector is in background of other variables,why?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

there is an image of what is happening, i'm not sure is this Unity bug,or what

Unity 2020.3.4 LTS

[inspector image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai1qc.png)

also some code

```
    [TextArea(3,10)]
    public string[] sentences;
    [TextArea(3, 10)]
    public string[] sentences2; 
    public string greeting;
    public string goodbye;
```

Comment: Sometimes the inspector repaint screws up.  Usually recompiling will fix it.  Make a change in a script and let unity recompile.  Check if the problem still exists.  If you have a custom inspector draw code, the problem is likely in that.

Comment: i've already recompiled,and even restarted Unity,this is class declared in another class
`public Dialogue dialogue;`

Answer (score 0):

try this?

[TextArea(3, 10)][Space(10)]

public string[] sentences2;

Comment: Unfortunately didn't help

Comment: one last option is assets>reimport all @tommer